# bg command seems not to behave

Tags: linux, bash

Could anyone shed some light on this matter ?

```
[root@test1 work]# tsung -f tsung_catalin_filetrans.xml start &
[2] 6284
[root@test1 work]# Starting Tsung
"Log directory is: /root/.tsung/log/20130201-2047"


[2]+  Stopped                 tsung -f tsung_catalin_filetrans.xml start
[root@test1 work]# jobs
[1]-  Stopped                 vim tsung_catalin_muc_dumbed.xml
[2]+  Stopped                 tsung -f tsung_catalin_filetrans.xml start
[root@test1 work]# bg 2
[2]+ tsung -f tsung_catalin_filetrans.xml start &
[root@test1 work]# jobs
[1]-  Stopped                 vim tsung_catalin_muc_dumbed.xml
[2]+  Stopped                 tsung -f tsung_catalin_filetrans.xml start
```

that tsung script wouldn't run in the background. How come ?

Comment: Does the script require input? (It can not get that while in the background, which would cause it to stop).

Comment: uhm, how do I find out ? input as int keyboard / mouse input or ?

Comment: keyboard input. Try running it in the foreground (without bg or &). If it ask something like: "Ready to start (y/n) then you know it is waiting for input. If it takes to long, start it in screen. (You detach (sort of background screen with control-A D. Getting it back is done with `screen -r`. Screen will keep running even if you log out).

Comment: it doesn't take any keys in. As for screen, it looks overly complicated for the matter at hand - I would rather keep it for a last resort.  It has  to be something else causing it not to bg.

Comment: As a variation on @Hennes’ suggestion: Do what you have been doing so far.  When `tsung` stops, bring it into the foreground with `fg` and see what happens.  If nothing happens (or if _something_ happens!), press (Ctrl)+Z and try `bg` again.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the job shows stopped is:

Any job that is not the terminal session leader (like backgound job) that attempts to do I/O
against the terminal raises signals: SIGTTOU or SIGTTIN - one for trying to write to the terminal and one for trying to read fromn the terminal.

bash intercepts the signal and puts the backgound process into a stopped state.

To handle output try:

```
some command > outputfile  &
```

to deal with input try to write to stdin of the command:

```
echo "answer1
answer2
" | command &
```

where answer1 and answer2 are the responses to prompts.